# Localization for Async Python Telegram bot

Tags: python, asynchronous, localization, internationalization, gettext

We have asynchronous python application (telegram bot), and we want to add localization: user selects language when he starts dialog with bot, then bot translates all messages for him.

Django allows to change language for every request, it is working normally, because Django create separate process for each request. But it will not work in async bot — there is only one process and we should handle multiple users with different languages inside of it.

We can do simple thing — store user's preferences in Database, load the preferred language from DB with each incoming message, and them pass this settings to all inside functions — but it is quite complicated, because our bot is complex and there can be more than dozen included function calls.

How we can implement language switching in the asynchronous application with elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we solved problem using `with` that provide us with context to all inner function calls.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Python, the way to share settings values with a stack of function calls without messing with other contexts, is by using `contextvars.Contextvar` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html  - those were introduced due to the need of holding different contexts in different asyncio tasks, but will work just fine for multi-threading apps as well.